# Click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have number of divs on my page of 2 types. The 1st type is "main item" the second is the "sub item". I hid the subitems using css and I want to show them back when we click on the main item. I have tried but its not working.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    Item 1
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 1
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 2
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 2
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 3
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 4
    <div class="sub-item">  
        Sub Item 4
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    Item 5
    <div class="sub-item">  
         Sub Item 5
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu .item {
    color: White;
    width: 250px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 35px;
    color:black;
}

.menu .sub-item {
    margin-left: 15px;
    display:none;
}
```

**JS/jQuery**

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $(this).child().show();
});
```

Also, here is the fiddle : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ba3h/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `child` function. You might have want to use [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) but it's cleaner to be more selective. Use this :

```
$(".item").click(function() {
    $('.sub-item', this).show();
});
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/eceyav/1/)**

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui No. Did you test it ?

Comment: sorry, i forgot the "this" keyword, I am reaully very sorry! :(

Comment: @AreebSiddiqui Did you notice the `this` in `$('.sub-item', this)` ? It limits the search.

Comment: @landons I don't think it's cleaner. It wouldn't work with an intermediate element layer and it's cleaner to only show what's hidden.

Comment: @dystroy That's true, but your way wouldn't work with more levels of sub-items ;)

Comment: @landons that thing makes another thing easier for me :P

Answer (score 4):

Your jsfiddle was missing a few things. First you didn't have the jQuery library selected. Second you need to be running your jQuery in the document.Ready event, otherwise jQuery isn't defined yet.

Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ba3h/3/).

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".item").click(function () {
            $(this).children('.sub-item').show();
        });
    });
```

You can use the `.children()` method in jQuery to select child elements, but as others mentioned `.child()` is not a method.

Comment: Note that the `document.ready` is useless both in jsfiddle with default settings and in a HTML document if the script is, as is usually recommended, in a script element at the end of the body. This being said it's good to point that the jQuery library wasn't included in the fiddle so +1 from me.

Comment: didn't know that about jsfiddle, thanks for the tip! that was the first thing I added when I looked at his fiddle, thats when I noticed jQuery wasn't loaded! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
jQuery(document).delegate('.item', 'click', function(e) {
   $('.sub-item', this).show();
});
```